# script to check the checkboxes of a GUI?

Tags: c#

i created a GUI and i am supposed to create another script that can

1. automate the running of GUI
2. check the boxes of the GUI
3. load a profile into GUI (GUI is made to be serializable by xml)

anybody can direct me to somewhere to create such automations?

with regards to 1, i can do windows scheduled task for now

Comment: means to create a script to run an .exe file

Comment: and inside the .exe file there are checkboxes.. so it would be good that this script can check the checkboxes in the .exe

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to do something that a macro can take care of. It sounds like you're just trying to get things done, rather than learn how to write your own macro machine, so I will refer you to Auto Hot Key to get you started: http://www.autohotkey.com/

Essentially, you can write an AHK script that the main Auto Hot Key program executes. The script can be programmed to run a program, check boxes (as a mouse or keyboard, doesn't matter), and read files in.

Their documentation is decent to help you get started as well: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand you, but I think you are talking about GUI automation.
Check out this links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163301.aspx
http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/
http://white.codeplex.com/

and check link from **Jordan**